# TypeScript: plugin:prettier/recommended for eslint, unable to use the override keyword

Tags: typescript, eslint, prettier

Package versions:

```
eslint@7.32.0
prettier@2.4.1
eslint-plugin-prettier@4.0.0
```

I've got the following eslintrc, which is just the stock config from NestJS:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin',
    'filenames'
  ],
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
    'filenames/match-regex': [2, "^[0-9a-z-.]+$", true]
  },
};
```

This is the prettier config:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all"
}
```

And this is the tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "incremental": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true
  }
}
```

In my code, I have a class like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseStrategy extends PassportStrategy(
  FirebaseAuthStrategy,
  'firebase',
) {
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {
    super({ extractor: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken() });
  }

  override async validate(payload: FirebaseUser): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return this.usersService.findByFirebaseUid(payload.uid);
  }
}
```

This code runs fine, but when I try to lint, I get the following error:

```
/app/src/auth/strategy/firebase.strategy.ts
  22:12  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token  prettier/prettier
```

Is there a way to fix this? I'd prefer not to have implicit overrides.

Comment: Can you please add .prettierrc & tsconfig.json?

Comment: @LongNguyen added, thanks for looking.

Comment: why you adding `prettier/recommended` to extend instead of plugin list?

Comment: I'm not doing anything, this is nestjs default configuration: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/.eslintrc.js and is the recommended config for esplugin-plugin-prettier: https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier/blob/master/README.md?plain=1#L73

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you need to update prettier to any version after 2.3.1 - support was added in that release for TypeScript 4.3 features like the override keyword. You can update this in package.json or use `npm i -D prettier@^2.3.1` (assuming you're using npm as your package manager).

Comment: I have prettier "^2.3.2" in my pakcage.json, guess that is not it

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know then other than trying to update all pretter/eslint packages